# Uniform continuity of $f(x)=(1-\cos(x))/\sin(x)$ on the interval $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

I got this question:

Prove that the function $f(x)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,1)$

I tried to prove it directly using the definition of uniform continuity but I failed this way. Then I tried to prove it using the fact that the sum of two uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous by writing $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \cot(x)$ and then I tried to show that both $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ and $cot(x)$ are uniformly continuous on (0,1) but I wasn't managed to proceed that much.

Some hints will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: At $x=0$ both $f(x)$, $1/sin(x)$ and $cot(x)$ has discontinuities.

Comment: But $x = 0$ does not belong to $(0,1)$.

Comment: Hint: Double-angle formulae.

Comment: $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x/2)+\cos^2(x/2)-(\cos(x/2)\cos(x/2)-   \sin(x/2)\sin(x/2))}{2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}=\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}=\tan(x/2)$

Comment: @user88595: But a singularity on the boundary of the domain implies that there is no uniform continuity... (I haven't checked this but I'm pretty sure it's at least true in $\mathbb R$).

Comment: @EricStucky: I was wondering the same... But if you take the definition of continuity literally, it is satisfied isn't it?

Comment: @user88595: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity/ is slightly stronger than ordinary continuity. In ordinary continuity, the $\delta$ is allowed to depend on the $x$, but in uniform continuity you need a single $\delta$ that works for all $x$. (In particular, while ordinary continuity is a pointwise construction, uniform continuity is a construction over the entire domain)

Comment: @EricStucky : Yes I did read this but I can't come up with a counter-example. Say we take $\frac{1}{x}$ on interval $(0,1)$, how do we show it's no uniformly continuous?

Comment: @user88595: If we choose a $\delta$, then our enemy can choose $\epsilon=1$ and $x=\delta$ (we can't stop him). Now consider the image of the $\delta$-neighborhood of $x$, and observe it is unbounded; in particular it is not contained within the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $f(x)=1/x$, so there's no uniformity. This is a pretty extreme example, because it didn't even matter what $\epsilon$ he chose. A more typical example of nonuniform continuity would be $f(x)=x^2$, where the trick is to go out to a very large $x$ so that the function is increasing very quickly.

Comment: @EricStucky: Get it now, thanks!

Comment: @derivative thanks for the hint.

Comment: since this function is differentiable on $(0,1) and it’s derivative is bounded on $(0,1)$, then it is in fact Lipschitz on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You can extend $f$ continuously to $[0,1]$ and continuous functions on closed intervals are uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}=\cdots$$

Answer (score -1):

Extension to Simon's answer:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{1-\cos\,x}{\sin\,x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x}}=0$$
the limit exists, so you can extend $f$ from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. If you meant to extend on Simon Markett's answer, please state so explicitly.